# SSRS Subscription: Send Email on Report Failure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report with some pre-selected parameters.

[image: Report Parameters]

Every once in a while, a report parameter will randomly blank itself out and the subscription won't create the file.

Is there a way I can be emailed in the event that the server can't create the report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, I ended up by creating configuring the Database Mail and creating an Operator to notifies me when the underlying job of the subscription fails.

1. Configure [Database Mail](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951(v=sql.105).aspx) to send a mail through a SMTP server even gmail or outlook works.
2. Create an [Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-an-operator), Operators are aliases for people or groups that can receive electronic notification when jobs have completed or alerts have been raised.

[image]

3. Identify the underlying job that runs your subscription, use this query against the `ReportServer` database.

`SELECT
c.Name AS ReportName
, rs.ScheduleID AS JOB_NAME
FROM
dbo.Catalog c
JOIN dbo.Subscriptions s ON c.ItemID = s.Report_OID
JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule rs ON c.ItemID = rs.ReportID
AND rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID`

The `JOB_NAME` column will give you the name of the job.

4. SQL Server Agent via SSMS go to the `Jobs` folder look for the job and right click it to go to properties.
5. In the Notifications tab set the `Operator` created before and the condition to send the mail.

[image]